# How to silence "variable not used" warning and maintain a strong reference?

Tags: swift

I'd like to silence the warning I get for not using my `timer` variable without using `_ = DispatchSource.createRepeating` and preferably without printing it or using it in a superfluous way.

```
func testTimerIsStarted() {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: #function)

    let timer = DispatchSource.createRepeating(interval: 0, deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.02)
}
```

> *Initialization of immutable value 'timer' was never used;
>   consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it*

The reason for not using `_` is because without a strong reference my expectation is never fulfilled as DispatchSource is immediately released without a strong reference.

**DispatchSourceExtension**

```
extension DispatchSource {
    public static func createRepeating(interval: Double,
                                       deadline: DispatchTime = .now(),
                                       queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
                                       mockTimer: DispatchSourceTimerScheduler? = nil,
                                       handler: @escaping () -> Void) -> DispatchSourceTimerScheduler {
        guard let timer = mockTimer ?? DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue) as? DispatchSourceTimerScheduler else {
            preconditionFailure("DispatchSourceTimer no longer complies with DispatchSourceTimerScheduler")
        }
        let leeway = estimateLeeway(for: interval)
        timer.schedule(deadline: deadline, repeating: interval, leeway: leeway)
        timer.setEventHandler(qos: .unspecified, flags: [], handler: handler)
        timer.resume()

        return timer
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not even sure this guarantees that lifetime of `timer` will exist after the line it's declared on. I'm not sure what the optimizers rules of engagement are here, but I suspect it sees it as unused and optimizes it out completely, causing an instant deallocation of the `DispatchSource` as soon as the initializing line is finished.

Comment: This does not compile, there is no `DispatchSource.createRepeating()` method.

Comment: @MartinR Could you explain if this is a case where something like `_fixLifetime` is necessary? https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/LifetimeManager.swift#L47-L52 I'm not sure if that's only necessary when dealing with raw pointer accesses (that the optimizer can't reason about), or in the general case of any usages of a strong reference

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, it's an extension. I'll include it now.

Comment: I would simply add `timer.cancel()` at the end of the test method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the use case of the [`withExtendedLifetime(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime) global function.

```
func testTimerIsStarted() {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: #function)

    let timer = DispatchSource.createRepeating(interval: 0, deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    withExtendedLifetime(timer) { timer in
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.02)
    }
}
```

But I'm not a fan of this approach, in general. It's more effort, but I think that tests like this should use mock time, that prevents actually spawning threads, waiting for "real" time to elapse, etc. When doing this, if you execute your unit test during a period of high system load (e.g. running test in parallel, or if you have other processes cranking), your test will give a false failure. Thus using simulated time is more reliable, not to mention faster.

Comment: I agree with the mocked time. I made an exception for this one test to ensure `timer.resume()` is called. I didn't feel comfortable just intercepting that method with a mock as it would still pass if someone called `timer.cancel()` immediately after.

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna I don't think your timer should be public, the option to make a rogue call to `timer.cancel()` should just be made impossible. Instead, the timer should be encapsulated in a data type that enforces invariants like this.

Comment: Mock time is one of the things I use with `RxSwift`. You can just say that events happen at  t = 5, 10, 15, and then your unit test can make assertions that those events actually did occur, and precisely at t = 5, 10, 15 https://www.raywenderlich.com/7408-testing-your-rxswift-code

Comment: Is `let timer` not sufficient to retain the reference until the test function has finished?

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna I'm not sure. I don't think the optimizer has any way of knowing that `timer` isn't useless. I suspect the optimizer will `release` it as soon as the defining line is finished. I'd love someone else to explain it! @Hamish, we're calling for you!

Comment: Yup this is a correct usage of `withExtendedLifetime` – unlike languages like C, in Swift the optimiser is free to deinitialise local variables before the end of the scope they're defined in. By using `withExtendedLifetime`, the compiler guarantees that the variable will remain valid for that given scope. Note that this wouldn't be necessary for something like `Timer`, as the run loop keeps a strong reference to it. For `DispatchSourceTimer` however, you're responsible for keeping it retained.